# Onclick, each loop and this woes

Tags: jquery, loops, onclick, this, each

Been searching high and low for a solution to this, but it's a difficult thing to search for. So here goes:

I have an onclick function:

```
$(".div-colour-box").on("click", function () {
```

Which enters an each loop:

```
$("#" + componentID).children("div.div-colour-box").each(function (i) {
```

I then want to check if the < div > that triggered the onclick function is the item that's currently being iterated in the each loop.

However, as far as I can see, when using jQuery, $(this) changes to refer to the item currently being iterated within the each loop, and effectively *forgets* which object triggered the onClick event.

How can I compare the two to see if they're one and the same?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Save your initial element to a variable:

```
$(".div-colour-box").on("click", function () {
    var clickedOn = this;
    $("#" + componentID).children("div.div-colour-box").each(function (i, element) {
        if(element == clickedOn) {
            //...
        }
    });
});
```

Comment: Shouldn't it be `e.target` ?

Comment: No, e is the name of the current element in the `each` loop. Maybe i should have chosen a different name.

Comment: e is a generic name for the parameter being passed to the function in the each loop.  In an each function (http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.each/) the first parameter is the index of the current item and the second is the current item in the iteration.

Comment: Exactly :) I changed the name to element now, so no one confuses it with the common name for event arguments.

Comment: Lovely. Worked perfectly.

Thanks a bunch, and thanks for the extra comment @Snowburnt. Helped me understand the .each method a lot more too!

Answer (score 0):

change:

```
$(".div-colour-box").on("click", function () {
```

to

```
$(".div-colour-box").on("click", function (e) {
```

use: `$(e.currentTarget)` to get the jquery object that triggered the click event.

Comment: That's not a good idea, because `e.target` and `this` are not always the same. [`e.currentTarget`](http://api.jquery.com/event.currentTarget/) would be much better.